# Highcharts no seeing change in numbers

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart in high charts and using numbers that are not whole

```
23: 88.242705
24: 88.2427051
25: 88.2427052
26: 88.2427051
27: 88.2427052
28: 88.2427053
29: 88.2427052
```

like so, The chart itself is only reading the 88 and nothing after the point

I'm not sure if anything can be done but has anyone had any experience.

My chart options right now are:

```
chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          zoomType: "x"
        },
        title: {
          text: "",
          style: {
            display: "none"
          }
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
          labels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: "Profit",
            allowDecimals: true
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        lang: {
          noData: "Place a bet and watch."
        },
        series: [
          {
            type: "spline",
            name: "Profit",
            animation: false,
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            },
            data: []
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Please post a full [MCVE]. As it is now, it is hard to understand if it is the tooltip that is showing 88, the axis labels, or both.

Comment: See this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/go7ub5yz/). It seems to be correct with your options. Is this what you are trying to display?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I want but mine is not doing it

Comment: Hi GrahamMorbyDev, Please see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jLpm64wx/, everything works fine with your data and options. Could you provide us with live demo which present your problem?